# Wrong date format when reading from elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, pyspark

I'm reading data from elactisearch index. I have date format issue 1501545600000 which is supposed to be in yyyy/mm/dd format.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

q ="""{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }  
}"""

es_read_conf = {
    "es.nodes" : "localhost",
    "es.port" : "9200",
    "es.resource" : "sub1",
    "es.query" : q
}

es_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    inputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat",
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable", 
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", 
    conf=es_read_conf)

 df2 = [convert_ts(doc) for doc in df]
```

this used to work; no longer because I changed the code

```
    try:
        ts_from_doc = get('Refill_Bar_End_Date_and_Time', None)

        if not ts_from_doc:
            raise ValueError('`Refill_Bar_End_Date_and_Time` not found')

        # incoming as millisec so convert to sec
        as_date = dt.fromtimestamp(
            int(ts_from_doc / 1000.0)
        ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        hit['Refill_Bar_End_Date_and_Time'] = as_date

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```

What do I have to modify to make it work?